# Are there online ship crew and passenger lists for journeys South Africa to New Zealand?

Tags: ship, manifest, south-africa, new-zealand, tasmania

I am looking for details on an individual surnamed Noye. He possibly was a passenger or crew member from Africa to Tasmania or Africa to New Zealand, in the late 1890s. Are there any online resources for ship voyages from South Africa?

Comment: Why do you believe he might have been a "passenger or crew member from Africa to Tasmania or Africa to New Zealand, in the late 1890s"?

Comment: Ancestry has plenty of arrivals in Australia - on the ones I just checked it seemed difficult to tell just from the list where the ship had come from. You might need newspaper reports to find the origin of the ships. But I suspect also there's every possibility that ships *from* to UK *to* the Antipodes could call in at South Africa en route, so I wouldn't give up on a UK origin ship simply because of that origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two great online historical newspaper sites that I use frequently, and they both list departing and arriving ships' passengers' names (sometimes just a surname).

The site for Australian newspapers is the National Library of Australia's [Trove](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper) (a true treasure trove in my opinion).

The site for New Zealand newspapers is [Papers Past](http://paperspast.natlib.govt.nz/cgi-bin/paperspast).

They both have very flexible search facilities, and both have papers going back to the time period in which you are looking. On Papers Past you can refine your search to show preview images, and your search term is always highlighted, making it easy to spot. The Trove results give you the OCR text.

Answer (score 12):

You might try searching on http://immigrantships.net/ There are many ships' manifests transcribed there, although it can be hard to find the info due to the way the site is indexed and organized.

Answer (score 10):

The Tasmanian Government offers an [Index to passengers & ships arrivals - 19th Century](http://portal.archives.tas.gov.au/menu.aspx?search=91). It is stated to be incomplete "so far entries for names beginning A to K have been converted" but there clearly are some N entries because Captain Noyes (master of the *Marquis of Lansdowne* in 1830) is found.

This may be a site to bookmark for future reference.

Comment: That is very encouraging and a site not seen before. As it happens, the surname I am looking for is Noyes.